# How to get react components in a separate static js file read by Django? What is the least to be installed to make it work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, babeljs

What are the modifications needed to be done ? And/or what is the least needed to be installed for this to work?

First, in a static reactclasses.js file
the file only contains this. (Is there anything else needed to be added?)

```
class Login extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="login">
                <form action="/login" method="POST">
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required/>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

In an html file

```
<!--- in the head tag --->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'reactclasses.js' %}" type="text/babel"></script>

<!--- in a script tag with type=text/babel in the body tag -->
ReactDOM.render(<login />, document.querySelector("thediv"));
```

[the console errors image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJz2K.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out a while back..
Here is a detailed scheme for how to do it
https://dev.to/zachtylr21/how-to-serve-a-react-single-page-app-with-django-1a1l

And 
[React component in JS file -- ReactDOM to be used in script in HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66529659/react-component-in-js-file-reactdom-to-be-used-in-script-in-html-file)

Comment: Useful answer, thanks! In line with the question, "What is the **least to be installed** to make it work?", is it possible to do this without Node.js? (in other words, without npm, just creating the files in the folders at the right place?) It seems a shame to have to install and learn Node just to create some files. (And because we don't want to let JavaScript out of the it's browser home anyways )