# React component in JS file -- ReactDOM to be used in script in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, babeljs

How to import a component in a script in HTML file?
What are the modifications to be done to make the following work?
And should the Babel libraries be added to the HTML file? (Webpack and React are already installed)

In car.js

```
class Car extends React.Component {
   render() { return (<p>nice car</p>) }}
```

In page.html

```
...
<script type="text/babel">
   import Car from "static/car.js"      //<---------????????

   ReactDOM.render(<Car />, document.querySelector("#root"));
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do not need to `import Car from "static/car.js"` it will works in JS file.

for HTML need refarance like `<script   type="text/babel" src="static/car.js"></script>`

```html
<script src="static/car.js" type="text/babel"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
  ReactDOM.render(<Car />, document.querySelector("#root"));
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work.
it gives errors: 
       ```react is not defined, Unexpected token '<' , Car is not defined.```

Comment: @Silver please add ` type="text/babel"` in script tag